# If $f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n^2t}t^a$ , then $ \lim_{t \to 0}f(t) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $$ f(t)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n^2t}t^a , \hspace{5mm} t >0$$ for some $a>0$

Then show that $$ \lim_{t \to 0}f(t) = 0$$

---

[My attempt]

I think  $$ \lim_{t \to 0}f(t)=\lim_{t \to 0}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{-n^2t}t^a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lim_{t \to 0} e^{-n^2t}t^a=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}0=0$$

However, for changing limit and series , we need to uniform convergence of $f$

I tried to use weierstrass M - test but it didn't work.

I'm stuck here, how that solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The limit is not always zero. It depends on $a$.

Let $\theta(t) := \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}e^{-\pi  n^2 t}$ for $t >0$. It is well-known (and not hard to prove via Poisson summation) that
$$
\theta(t) = t^{-1/2}\theta(1/t)
$$
for all $t >0$. We can write
$$
f(t) = t^{a}\frac{\theta(t/\pi)-1}{2}  = t^{a}\frac{\pi^{1/2}t^{-1/2}\theta(\pi/t)-1}{2}.
$$
We have $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}{\theta(\pi/t)} = 1$ and so
$$
f(t) \sim t^{a}\frac{\pi^{1/2}t^{-1/2}-1}{2} \sim  \frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2 }t^{a-1/2},
$$
where $g(t)\sim h(t)$ means that $g(t)/h(t) \rightarrow 1$ as $t \rightarrow 0$. In summary, for $a \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}{f(t)} = \begin{cases}
\infty & a < 1/2\\
\frac{\pi^{1/2}}{2 } &a =1/2\\
0 & a>1/2
\end{cases}
$$
The last case can also easily be shown via a geometric series estimate.

Comment: Are you sure about the constant $\pi^{1/4}$? I am simply getting $\pi^{1/2}$ from the Gauss circle problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I corrected the (rather silly) mistake now.

Comment: Thank you, how to know that $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0}{\theta(\pi/t)} = 1$ ?

Comment: This is equivalent to $\lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{e^{-  n^2 s}}} = 0$, which can be proved in many ways, for example by factoring out $e^{-s/2}$ from the sum and bounding the rest uniformly in $s$.

Answer (score 3):

The question relates to the Gauss circle problem. Indeed by considering
$$ \Theta(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}e^{-n^2 x}$$
we have
$$ \Theta(-\log z)^2 = \sum_{N\geq 0} r_2(N) z^N $$
where $ r_2(N)=\left|\left\{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Z}^2:a^2+b^2=N\right\}\right| $. By Gauss geometric estimations we have
$$ \sum_{N=0}^{M}r_2(N) = \pi M + O(\sqrt{M}) $$
hence
$$ \frac{\Theta^2(-\log z)}{1-z}=\frac{\pi z}{(1-z)^2}+O\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\sqrt{n}z^n\right) $$
and
$$ \Theta(-\log z)\sim\sqrt{\frac{\pi z}{1-z}} $$
as $z\to 1^-$. This implies
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}e^{-n^2 x}\sim -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi e^{-x}}{1-e^{-x}}}\sim -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{x}} $$
as $x\to 0^+$.

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio, why we may be sure that $\sum_n O(\sqrt{n})z^n$ is "good"? I think it's better to mention that in our case we may write $\theta(n) \le 100 \sqrt{n}$ instead of $ O(\sqrt{n})$ - I mean that all $O(\sqrt{n})$ have the same constant.

Comment: The remainder series may still have a singularity at $z=1$, but not worse than $\frac{1}{(1-z)^{3/2}}$.