# A limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} e^{-2k^2 x^2} = \frac12$ and continuity of Kolmogorov distribution.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, statistics

Problem: prove that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} e^{-2k^2 x^2} \to \frac12, x\to 0,$$
not using theta-function.

Motivation:

Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic is well known. It's limit distribution has a continious distribution function $F(x)$ such that $F(x) = 0$ for $x \le 0$ and $$F(x) = 1 - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} e^{-2k^2 x^2}  = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{x} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(2k-1)^2 \pi^2}{8x^2}}$$
otherwise.

The equivalence of two expressions $F_1(x) = 1 - 2 \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} e^{-2k^2 x^2}$ and  $F_2(x) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{x} \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(2k-1)^2 \pi^2}{8x^2}}$ follows easily from transformation formula for theta-functions.

Using $F_2(x)$ it's easy to prove that $F(x)$ is continuous for all $x$. Using $F_1(x)$ it's easy to prove that $F(x)$ is continuous for all $x \ne 0$. My question was the next one: is there any simple way to prove that $F(x) $ is continuous at $x=0$, using the definition with $F_1(x)$?

As $F_1(x)$ is even then the statement "$F_1(x) \to 0, x \to 0+$" is equivalent to the statement "$F_1(x) \to 0, x \to 0$". So, my question is: is there any simple way (without theta-functions) to prove that
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} e^{-2k^2 x^2} \to \frac12, x\to 0?$$

What do I know? I know that the statement  $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k-1} e^{-2k^2 x^2} \to \frac12, x\to 0$ follows from properties of theta-functions, but the question is about simple methods. I thought about the next idea: if $x=0$, then we have divergent series $S = 1 - 1 + 1 - 1 + 1 - \ldots = 1 - S$. It's a wrong way, but in some sense it's natural to write $S= 1 -S$ and hence $S = \frac{1}2$. Unfortunatelly, $S$ doesn't exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lots of questions about the Gauss circle problem today! Well, the number of lattice points in $x^2+y^2\leq N$ is $\pi N+O(\sqrt{N})$, and this implies that for $x\to 0^+$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} e^{-n^2 x} = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{x}}+O(\sqrt{x}) $$
as shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3959227/if-ft-sum-n-1-infty-e-n2tta-then-lim-t-to-0ft-0/3959331#3959331), so
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} e^{-2n^2 x} = -\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{8x}}+O(\sqrt{x}) $$
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} e^{-8n^2 x}=-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{8x}}+O(\sqrt{x}) $$
as $x\to 0^+$. By absolute convergence
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}(-1)^{k+1}e^{-2k^2 x}=-\sum_{k\geq 1}e^{-2k^2 x}+2\sum_{k\geq 1}e^{-8k^2 x}=\frac{1}{2}+O(\sqrt{x}) $$
as $x\to 0^+$. Actually, by the very same argument, all the right derivatives of the LHS at $x=0$ equal zero, so the LHS belongs to $(C^{\infty}\setminus C^{\omega})(\mathbb{R}^+)$.

Comment: Very unexpected connection with Gauss circle problem! Thank you!